# in JS, why do dates that occur on the first of each month get sorted into previous month when I map over an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, iso, array.prototype.map

How do I get expenses that occur on the first of each month to appear with the rest of the expenses for that month?
In this case, I have a component that brings in the state data for all of the expenses in the database and then I call a function to map over it to place each expense in its corresponding month:

```
const expensesData = useSelector((state)=>state?.financialsReducer?.expenses)

const monthlyExpenses = (m) => {
        const expenseArray = expensesData?.map((e)=>{
            if(new Date(e.date).getMonth() === m) {
                return e.amount
            } else {
                return null
            }
        })
        return expenseArray.reduce((accumulator, current)=> accumulator + current, 0).toFixed(2)
    }

const juneExpenses = monthlyExpenses(5)
const julyExpenses = monthlyExpenses(6)
```

The problem is, expenses that occur on the first of each month are appearing in the results for the previous month. For example, if I have an expense on July 1 2022, it appears in the results for juneExpenses.

Here's a specific example. This object appears only when the monthlyExpenses function is called with m = 5 (that is, for the month of June). The expenses' date is clearly for the month of July/7.

```
{_id: '1212saf23423df04fb10', date: '2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z', year: '2022', category: 'rent', amount: 1176, …}
amount: 1176
category: "rent"
date: "2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
details: ""
year: "2022"
__v: 0
_id: "1212saf23423df04fb10"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Is it timezone difference?

Comment: maybe you want getUTCMonth

Comment: Every dev reading this is feeling the pain of scars that will never heal. Timezones are a blight and a menace.

Answer (score 2):

If it's happening only the first of the month, it's likely a timezone issue. That is, your data is from UTC, but your testing environment is UTC-(something), so your date is effectively on the last day of the previous month.

You can fix this by standardizing where your dates are set.

Edit: by "standardizing where," I mean "standardizing in what timezone" your dates are set. So basically, add a timezone to your datasets, or add a timezone offset to your testing environment.

Comment: Do you know of any good resources for learning how to use dates and timezones in Javascript? I've always had an issue understanding this.

Comment: Follow-up question: should I store dates as iso strings in my database? Or should I store them in a different format?

Comment: This is a "quick and dirty" article that I find useful but brief enough to reference regularly: [Everything You Need to Know About Date in JavaScript](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-date-in-javascript/). It even details the issue you're having here. For your follow-up, ISO strings are a perfectly valid and stable way to store dates. Less-standard strings that the browser tries to parse can get you into trouble, though. Other date formats would be based on your needs/preferences.